# How does brainstorming look like for a team like Google's "Project Zero"

Tags: exploit-development, zero-day

The question is not necessary about technical details but more broad. **I'm fascinated by the creativity involved in this process.**

Since the news of Meltdown/Spectre I was wondering: How do teams like Project Zero come up with ideas to find 0-day exploits? Especially if we think of the ones mentioned which were there for decades.

Do they come in in the morning, get their coffee and say: "What would be the worst thing that could be exploited? Lets target the CPU!". And then spend an enormous amount of time studying it?

Or is it something like a coincidence: "While developing some tool I accidentally read some memory and I wondered why I was allowed to do this..."

I guess if you have a team dedicated to exploits, they wouldn't go after something by pure chance.

**Edit:**
I'm not sure if it is a duplicate of [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47097/how-are-zero-days-found). The reason: I'm not asking about the techniques of finding the exploit. It is more general: How do they even decide on a possible "victim" software. As far as I understand Project Zero, they generally try to find exploits - no matter where.

Maybe @Overmind is right though and it is too broad to ask such a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad and not really related to security, but as a general rule, if you want to discover unique things, you must follow the special path of out-of-box thinking.

From a team's leadership perspective, each opinion is considered, each scenario checked no matter how strange it may seem. If fact, the strangest the idea, the higher the priority it should have.

From a team member's perspective, you must do exactly what noone else expects, tries or even thinks to do.

So a bunch of very good people are not enough, not even close to enough. You need members that are used to innovations, you need them to work both as a team and independently and you need to properly lead them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint: Where should I / would you ask this question? I understand it is not directly related to security although it is asked in the context of security. I thought it might be a good place as it has a direct purpose - a general question like "how do you find ideas on what you could do with something you don't know" in some other stackexchange would be even less productive.

Comment: I think it was more fit for https://workplace.stackexchange.com